# Blackbody radiation, de Broglie equation, and lightwaves to be shifted left

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, thermal-radiation, wavelength

I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

1. Say we heated a lead ball to 1,000 Kelvin. Not all of the particles
   are at the *exact* same temperature--some parts are a little hotter,
   some are a little cooler. But for now, let’s assume that it follows a normal
   distribution that is centered at 1,000K.
2. The heat (or movement of the molecules) causes it to emit light.
3. Because the light photons have to be discrete (you can't have a 1/2 photon), this causes the observed light wavelengths to be shifted left.
4. This means we observe more red light than we might otherwise expect.
5. This is a long wind up to my specific question--*does a particle vibrating at a specific frequency emit light at the same frequency?* (i.e. a particle vibrating at 4.3 MhZ emits light at 4.3 Mhz). Because it seems like the whole thing hinges on that.

I mention this because I asked a physics teacher this, and he said, “*No, the particles emit light following the de Broglie equation.*”  This would mean that the light emitted ignores the frequency and instead is based solely on its momentum.  But, if this were true, then I would assume it would emit light in a standard distribution of frequencies as opposed to the left-skewed distribution that is actually observed.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your point three

> Because the light photons have to be discrete (you can't have a 1/2 photon), this causes the observed light wavelengths to be shifted left.

is incorrect. What is quantized is not what energies that can be emitted (those are continuous and correspond to frequency), but the amount of energy emitted at any particular frequency.

That is there is no rule that says you can emit light with photon energies of $E$ or $E + \epsilon$ or $$E + 2\epsilon$, or $E + 3\epsilon$ and so on.

But there is a rule that says if you are emitting light with a frequency that corresponds to energy $E$ or out unit then you can emit $E$ or $2E$ or $3E$, etc. *in that frequency*. You can still emit $\frac{\pi}{4}E$, but it happens by emitting a *different frequency*.

I'm afraid this means the foundation of the rest of your argument is unsound.

The cause for the shape of the blackbody spectrum is the thermo-statistics of such quantized emissions.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response! I do have a few questions though.  So I know energy is not quantized (E=hv). If you can have any frequency, you can have any energy.  However, correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that temperature would be distributed in a somewhat standard bell-curve: some outliers both above and below the average temperature, and the majority of lead atoms are close to the average temperature.  What I am most confused about though is the frequency of light emitted by a particle vibrating at a specific frequency;  would a particle vibrating at 5MHz emit light also at 5MHz?